# pdf text doesn't align

Tags: pdf, jspdf

I am trying to align a text but it gets out of the sheet.

If I put right alignment it goes away, if I center it is left and half of the text is hidden.

```
var doc = new JsPDF()
doc.text('something', 0, 10, { align: 'center' })
doc.save('pdfName' + '.pdf')
```

***I posted a picture but I have no reputation for it.*** :(

Comment: What is the unit you use while initiating the jsPDF variable "**doc**"?

Comment: I edited the description

Comment: I used these parameter and here's how I get the output. 
[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/7G49rXO)